# Dynamically get a tag in Play 2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Let's say I have 3 tags, smallTag, mediumTag, and largeTag.

Assuming that I have the value of size as a `String`, how can I dynamically get the tag that I want?  I'm looking for something like...

```
views.html.tags.get(size + "Tag")
```

I realize I can accomplish this with if/then statements, but I'm trying to figure out how to get it dynamically, based on a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to use `match case` statement as described in [Common template use cases](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaTemplateUseCases) in section `Tags (they are just functions right?)`.